# prolog eliminate the first n-th elements from sublists

Tags: prolog

I want to write a program in prolog which deletes the first n sublists having the length even.
This is what I have:

```
 %calculates the length
 lung([],0).
 lung([_|T],R):-
 lung(T,R1),
    R is R1+1.
 %true if the length is even
 evenLength(T):-
    lung(T,Even),
    Even mod 2 =:=0.
 %true if the length is odd
 oddLength(T):-
    lung(T,Odd),
    Odd mod 2 =\=0.
 %eliminate the n given element from a list
 elim([],_,[]).
 elim([_|T],1,R):-
 elim(T,0,R).
 elim([H|T],N,[H|T1]):-
      N \=1,
      N1 is N-1,
      elim(T,N1,T1).
 %eliminate the n-th given element from a sublist where the length is even
 elimSublist([],_,[]).
 elimSublist([H|T],N,[K|R]):-
      is_list(H),
      evenLength(H), %**
      elim(H,N,K),
      elimSublist(T,N,R).
 %if the length of the sublist id odd than it goes further
 elimSublist([H|T],N,[H|R]):-
      is_list(H),
      oddLength(H),
      elimSublist(T,N,R).
      elimSublist([H|T],N,[H|R]):-
      elimSublist(T,N,R).
```

The problem is that if, for example I write:

```
 elimSublist([1,2,3,4,[1,2,4,5,6,2],[1,2,3]],2,R).
```

it gives me:
     R = [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 4, 5, 6|...], [1, 2, 3]]

I know that ** there should be the problem but how can I resolve that?Thank you.

Comment: it's just a visualization feature. Try to `?- elimSublist(..., R), writeln(R).`

Comment: See SWI Prolog documentation: [Help: I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html)